# Running background command with fabric (sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo)

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7, fabric

I am running a  script in background using fabric. To do that I am using below mentioned function.

```
def init_db(var):
    with cd("%s/scripts" % var):
            sudo (" nohup ./init_database.sh &> initdatabase.out &", pty=False)
```

I have to use pty=False to do it in backgound but this fails as in sudoers file "Defaults requiretty" option is mentioned which does not allow me to run sudo from fabric without pty.

I cannot edit the sudoers file all the time for every server, can anyone please give me some other solution.

Thanks,
Imran Teli

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: This is not safe! Do not use this!**

Fabric supports giving the `sudo` password in the shell command:

```
fab --password=password [...]
```

However, this means the password may be stored in the shell history, log files and other random places where they could be easily retrieved by anyone having any sort of access to the box.

**The safe way to do this** is, as you mentioned, setting up sudoers to allow exactly the things you expect the script to do, and nothing else, without a password.

Comment: If this was helpful, you may want to vote and/or set it as the accepted answer. If you feel it's not adequate or you would like to refine your original request, you can update the question as you like.